# Error in Phonegap Application: Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have been trying to resolve many issues from having updated from Phonegap 2 to Phonegap 3.3 but I can't seem to fix this one.

I have read from some users that uncaught module exceptions can cause imported plugins to stop functioning. I am having some odd bugs with a local notification plugin so I would like to fix this issue and see if it helps.

Here is the error as it appears in logcat within Eclipse:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(79)] "Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (79)
```

I know that this is some odd issue arising from the nature of Phonegap 3 (Plugins have been reworked). And I think that the problem lies in importing a cordova_plugins.js script as the top line of that script reads:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/DirectoryEntry.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.file.DirectoryEntry",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.DirectoryEntry"
    ]
}, ...
```

And this is the only place that I can find the existence of cordova/plugin_list as referenced in the error.

However, I am not sure of the correct way of fixing this issue. I did not use plugman to import my plugins, but instead the CLI commands outlined in the Phonegap 3.3 API

Comment: Hi, I reccomend to you not to upgrade, Create a new proyect with cordova from cli, install your plugins with cli too and copy your www old proyect to new one. I think that it'll prevent many kind of mistakes to you. Regards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One cause of this problem is importing the **cordova_plugins.js** in your html file.

Check if it is the case for you and remove it.

Comment: THank you grytrn, this solved the issue for me... I could have sworn that I needed that call to cordova_plugins.js, but it seems like my applicaiton is loading fine without it, and I am no longer receiving the error.

Comment: I don't have the cordova_plugins.js in my HTML file. But I still see the same problem with my project. Any clue on this @grytrn?

Comment: @LohithKrishna I was seeing this exception while trying to use cordova plugins in a remote site. See my answer in this thread. I'm not sure if you have the same situation or not.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26551455/534495

Comment: @LohithKrishna without details I can't help.

Comment: A whole pile of my troubles were rooted in this.  Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

The file **cordova.js** automatically loads **cordova_plugins.js**.

So another obvious way to end up with this error is if you inadvertently put the following code twice on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I lost hours on this same error only to realise I had added cordova.js at both the top and the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -4):

You must have to create and deploy any phonegap project/application using Phonegap Command Line Interface

To Create any project write following command on command line:

```
$ phonegap create <path> <package_name> <project_name>
```

i.e.

```
$ phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

To add any platform to your project:

```
cd <path_to_project>
$ phonegap build <platform>
```

i.e.

```
cd hello
$ phonegap build ios
$ phonegap build android
```

To add any plugin feature to your project:

```
cd <path_to_project>
$ phonegap local plugin add <path_to_plugin>
```

i.e.

```
cd hello
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```