# cordova upgrade issue to 3.2

Tags: android, cordova

when I upgraded my Android app to cordova 3.2 I am seeing below error in console please help.

"Uncaught module cordova/plugin_list already defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js (79)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is found in [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890263/error-in-phonegap-application-uncaught-module-cordova-plugin-list-already-defin)
Control if "cordova_plugins.js" is already included in your html files. If it is, remove that line.