# How to get access to phonegap API from a remote page

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have to following situation:
I have a already existing remote webpage and i want to develope an app which uses this page.
So far, so good. When I start the app the local `index.html` is loaded and it redirects (`window.open target: _self`) to the external website. This website is opened in the phonegap webview. On the external website I added the `cordova.js` in order to get access to the native phonegap API. But it doesn't work correctly. The **deviceReady** event is triggered correctly, but I have no access to the phonegap API, for example navigator.camera.

How can I get it done, to get access to the API?

Please do not comment that it will be rejected by AppStore etc. etc.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What phonegap version are you using?

Comment: R u using  InAppBrowser ??? If yes then you can't access Cordova API. Check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Comment: I am using version 3.3.0 and no the external website is loaded in the cordova WebView

Comment: I'm having the same issue using `window.location="http://your.website";` and also `<content src="http://your.website"" />`

Answer (score 13):

Well, for me the solution was a mixture of several sources, but most of the solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992306/2471497).

What you should do is the following:

1. Define your `config.xml` to point directly to the remote `index.html`.

   ```
   <content src="http://your-remote-location/index.html" />
   ```
2. In your `index.html` any reference to a local android device resource prepend with some unique prefix like `**injection**`. For instance for `cordova.js` you'll come up with something like:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="**injection**www/cordova.js"></script>
   ```
3. Find `SystemWebViewClient.java` under the following location: `your-project-location\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine`.
4. Add the following enum declaration in the private members section of the class at the top:

   ```
   private enum WebExtension {
       PNG, MP3, MP4, TTF, SVG, JS, ICO, HTML, CSS, EOT, WOFF, JSON;
   }
   ```
5. Locate the `shouldInterceptRequest` method and add the following right after the `try {` line:

   ```
   if(url != null && url.contains(INJECTION_TOKEN)) {
       String assetPath = url.substring(url.indexOf(INJECTION_TOKEN) + INJECTION_TOKEN.length(), url.length());
       try {
           String mimeType = "text/plain";

           String ext = assetPath.substring(assetPath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, assetPath.length());
           WebExtension extension = WebExtension.valueOf(ext.toUpperCase());

           switch(extension) {
               case PNG:
                   mimeType = "image/png";
                   break;
               case MP3:
                   mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
                   break;
               case MP4:
                   mimeType = "video/mp4";
                   break;
               case TTF:
                   mimeType = "application/x-font-ttf";
                   break;
               case SVG:
                   mimeType = "image/svg+xml";
                   break;
               case JS:
                   mimeType = "application/javascript";
                   break;
               case ICO:
                   mimeType = "image/x-icon";
                   break;
               case HTML:
                   mimeType = "text/html";
                   break;
               case CSS:
                   mimeType = "text/css";
                   break;
               case EOT:
                   mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
                   break;
               case WOFF:
                   mimeType = "application/x-font-woff";
                   break;
               case JSON:
                   mimeType = "application/json";
                   break;
           }

           WebResourceResponse response = new WebResourceResponse(
               mimeType,
               "UTF-8",
               parentEngine.webView.getContext().getAssets().open(assetPath)
           );
           return response;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); // Failed to load asset file
       }
   }
   ```

The result of all of it will be interception of every resource request and in case it will contain the `**injection**` string in it, it will cut down the resource location and will request it from local device location under which the application is running. The mimeType is necessary to load the resource in the correct manner by the app browser.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This Solutions is the best thing happen to me, it opens so many possibilities to Codorva development. This should be included in next Cordova version by default.

Answer (score 11):

Including the cordova.js script in the remote site is going to be tricky, because there's a different cordova.js for each platform. You could modify the server so that it returns the correct cordova.js based on the user agent, but this is also tricky because it will include this script when you view the site from a mobile browser, and this is undesirable because javascript errors might be shown to the user. Same story when viewing the site from a desktop computer, the cordova.js should not be included.

It looks to me that you have a local web page (with the cordova script included) and from there you change to the remote page (that also includes the script). I'm not sure this page change is going to work. If it worked, you might have to wait for the second deviceready event.

But you can just set the remote site page as the root page in the cordova app, no need for an intermediate "loader" page. Just set it in the config.xml file:

```
<content src="http://your.website.fake/index.html" />
```

You need to make sure that you allow loading your site in the app. In this same file, you should add:

```
<access origin="http://your.website.fake" subdomains="true"/>
```

Comment: I've tried it already, this way you are able to load the remote page, but not able to access the phongap api

Comment: What API are you using? If you are trying to use a third party plugin, AND provided you have included the plugin script in the site as well, it should work.

Comment: I'm using the built in camera plugin.
It doesn't work. 
The only workaround I've found is to load the remote page in an IFrame inside a local page. And use js postMessage to communicate between them. Yet this solution is inconvenient and causes other issues (Same origin etc).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "doesn't work" part? Can you check using console log if cordova has been loaded, and whether the camera object is defined? Try this with the xml config I posted, the hot page-change you are attempting sounds like the kind of thing that doesn't work well.

Comment: As I commented on the question itself, I've tried exactly what you are suggesting. I've also checked it in the console.. Cordova is defined yet all the plugins are not defined. The iframe solution was found here: https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/

Comment: If cordova is defined but the plugins are not, either you are not waiting for the `deviceready event`, or else the plugins are not included in the `config.xml` file. I've worked in a project where we ajax-loaded a remote page and used phonegap plugins without any problem, so it's definitely possible.

Comment: I've double checked that everything configured correct, and the same configuration and code works fine in local page.
It looks like it is intentionally blocked by Cordova, as suggested by Rivera below.
Yet, loading the remote page with Ajax sounds like something that could work, you should have started with that :) I'll try and update, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelS you have linked [this](https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/). Doesn't this work properly?

Comment: @AliNaciErdem: I haven't tested the AJAX page load yet, but I don't see a reason why it won't work, since i'm loading data to a local page.

Comment: @MichaelS I'm sorry to hear the ajax approach is the only valid right now. This should have been possible using the regular mechanism I posted, or even window.location. I'd have liked to make some tests, but right now I can't because I don't have a cordova 3.x install nor your code. But as I said, we were able to load remote pages using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap 2.9

Comment: @MichaelS I was referring to iFrame?

Comment: @AliNaciErdem: The iframe method works just fine. but it causes other issues. see details [here](https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/)

MisterSmith, I think i'll skip phonegap for my current project and simply use a [JS interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) that built in Android. I know it works with remote pages for sure.

Comment: I've tried both the ajax-loading and IFRAME approach on our projects, they both have issues. The IFRAME approach was preferred, but with iOS-10 we started having a lot of keyboard problems. I have been looking at [this plugin](https://github.com/manifoldjs/ManifoldCordova) and trying but not yet success, it claims that it can inject the cordova and plugin JS files into a remote web app. This would be ideal!

Answer (score 10):

This plugin solves the problem without having to code yourself an android solution.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-remote-injection

https://github.com/TruckMovers/cordova-plugin-remote-injection

> The remote injection plugin allows a remote site to interact with cordova's javascript APIs when loaded within your cordova app.
>
> - Injects cordova and installed plugin JS into the webview for any remotely browsed page allowing them the same access to the cordova object and its plugins as a packaged cordova app.
> - Support for iOS and Android platforms.

I tested it and it works just fine. The only thing you need to remember is that you'll need to wait for cordova to be ready, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          document.write("Now you can use plugins"); 
      }, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this still work? The plugin works on android but on ios I don't get access to cordova and the deviceready event is never triggered

Answer (score 7):

I've had this problem as well and changing things in config.xml(content and access tags) didn't work. I inspected the app while it was running on the phone and I discovered that when I loaded the remote site there were some files missing.

First off it's the file called **cordova_plugins.js** which you can find for each platform in the platform folder. Then you also need some plugin specific files. You can find these by doing a build and extracting them from there. For android the path is as follows APK/assets/www/plugins. Just copy the contents on your server and you're good to go.

**NOTE**: you can also find the plugin specific files in the platform folder, but they are incomplete as they're missing cordova.define("... at the beginning. This leads to **required** and **module** being undefined, so just do a build and get them from there.

Comment: this is great. But how to deal with platform specific plugins then? I mean, how to handle accessing a plugin from iPhone as well android phone?

Comment: Well how do you handle that when the HTML code is loaded locally? I presume you need to check what platform you're running on to know if the plugin is available or not. Cordova itself should know what it needs to load based on the plugin.xml file(I think that's what it's called) which is generated from the configuration file. You can do a regular android build and open up the APK to see what the file structure looks like.

Comment: This is great, it helped me a lot, first I used solution with iframes, but I wasn't happy with it, so I tried what @sorin suggested and it worked great.On server side one could use userAgent sniffing and detect if user is comming from an cordova app, then return additional scripts(cordova.js,cordova_plugins.js, and pluginSpecific.js..) . One could also add user specific "userAgent " string in Cordova to distinguish "normal" browser from cordova webview.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Cordova/PhoneGap imposed limitation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/1733e64e724007427056e03d0c65e58559de3951/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVViewController.m#L212):

```
    if (startFilePath == nil) {
        loadErr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR: Start Page at '%@/%@' was not found.", self.wwwFolderName, self.startPage];
        NSLog(@"%@", loadErr);
        self.loadFromString = YES;
        appURL = nil;
    }
```

I have disabled this check in the past to let Cordova work with non-local file addresses.

Comment: Where can I find the equivalent for Android?

Comment: Not sure. You'll need a separate answer/question or dig in the code which should work in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked to make it work for a very long time for phoneGap quick-debugging but could not find a way to make the API working without having the cordova.js together with the app (not on a remote location).

I don't know exactly why this does not work. If you know the internal workings I'm looking forward to hearing it...

The last thing I've tried was to put a 100% by 100% iframe in the main html and load the local cordova.js in the same document. Then I was able to use the API but there were some scaling issues on iOS, which is another question...

I do not remember the exact way I've implemented and structered this, but I'll edit if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest working solution which allows to load local file from a remote https page without mixed content errors:

For android: Disable mixed content policy using: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)

For ios: I submitted a PR to the file plugin which solves the mixed content problem on ios: apache/cordova-plugin-file#296 The fixed version is available at: https://github.com/guylando/cordova-plugin-file If you load a remote site https://example.com on the webview then it allows to access local files using the url: https://example.com/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js instead of cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js And by this solves the mixed content problems