# Cordova Opening Remote Sites while keeping access to cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I've compiled an app with a single index.html that loads `cordova.js`. 
The app is nothing more than a wrapper to my other cordova apps hosted in different servers.

I would like to be able to use window.location to access each one of these apps while being able to access the device controls such as "homebutton" event.

The problem is that after redirecting the user to one of my domains I lose the local context and as consequence I can't load the cordova.js anymore into my remotely hosted apps. The same goes for the plugins installed along with the distribution version.

- I could of course host and load different versions of cordova.js based on the device os that is running the app. So each app has it's own version of cordova.js hosted along it.
- But after being on a remote page how can i back to the application root page?

I found this related question:
[How to get access to phonegap API from a remote page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984688/how-to-get-access-to-phonegap-api-from-a-remote-page)

[image]